# Cannot access /path-to-repository/CVSROOT

Tags: cvs

I'm being unable to connect to a remote CVS server.

```
$ export CVSROOT=:ext:myusername@serverdomain.com:/path-to-repository
$ export CVS_RSH=/usr/bin/ssh

$ cvs co projects/projectname
myusername@serverdomain.com's password:  (Password works fine so it is connecting correctly to the server)

Cannot access /path-to-repository/CVSROOT
No such file or directory
```

Do you know what's going wrong?

I've also tried doing other cvs actions with the same result

```
$ cvs log projects/projectname
Cannot access /path-to-repository/CVSROOT
No such file or directory
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It can be you don't have read/write permission for the repository. Check it out accessing the server with ssh.